# Supervisor - Invalid user name

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I'm trying to run supervisor on Ubuntu 16.04. There was no problem in installation. I created file /etc/supervisor/conf.d/test.conf

```
[program:test]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /data/web/test.com/web/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/data/web/test.com/web/storage/logs/workers.log
```

But when I run command

```
supervisorctl reread
```

I'm getting following error:

ERROR: CANT_REREAD: Invalid user name forge in section 'program:test' (file: '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/test.conf')

Any ideas what's wrong? Tried to search for solution but still not working...

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | grep force   confirms that username exists ?

Answer (score 21):

The `user` is not a mandatory field in the Supervisor process config file, you can just comment the line with `;` if you don't need a specific user to run the task.

For example in a laravel artisan command:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
;user=forge
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
```

Comment: Just a word of caution to other Laravel users, not defining a user may allow the system root to create log and cache files that are inaccessible to your Laravel application.  This can result in a cascade of issues.  It is highly recommend to set an appropriate user for your worker according to the application.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it. Needed to define user in test.conf and now it's working.