# Error test-1 exited with code 2, Laravel sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I am using Laravel sail and MySQL and Mailhog packages. When I use the sail command, it shows me the following error:

**Terminal:**

> Error: Invalid user name sail in section 'program:php' (file:
> '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf')
>
> For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h

This is my file vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1/**supervisord.conf**

> ```
>  [supervisord]
>     nodaemon=true
>     user=root
>     logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
>     pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
>     
>     [program:php]
>     command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
>     user=sail
>     environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
>     stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
>     stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
>     stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
>     stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
> ```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3' services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

How could I fix this error and run my project again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Supervisor - Invalid user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574727/supervisor-invalid-user-name)

Comment: `cat /etc/passwd | grep sail` confirms that the username *exists or not*. Cross-check that first, please.